# What is $\inf \{p \in \mathbb{R} \mid e < (1+\frac{1}{x})^{x+p} \text{ for any } x > 0\}$?

Tags: calculus, inequality

[image]

This problem is from an entrance examination for a university in Japan.

> Prove the following inequality:
> $(1+\frac{1}{x})^{x} < e < (1+\frac{1}{x})^{x+\frac{1}{2}}$ for any $x > 0$.

I have the following question:

> What is $\inf \{p \in \mathbb{R} \mid e < (1+\frac{1}{x})^{x+p} \text{ for any } x > 0\}$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$p=\frac{1}{2}$ is the infimum.

Since the Japanese entrance exam
guarantees that the inequality holds for $p=1/2$, we need to check
that if $p<1/2$ then there exists some $x>0$ that violates the inequality.

Assume $p>0$. The derivative of the function $f(x)=(1+1/x)^{x+p}$ as a function of $x$
is $(1+1/x)^{p+x}(\log(1+1/x)-{p+x\over (1+1/x)x^2})$. Consider the function
$g(x)=(1+1/x)\log(1+1/x)x^2-x$. Then one checks that $g(x)$ is monotonically increasing and $\lim_{x\to\infty}g(x)=1/2$, so in particular $g(x)<1/2$ for all $x>0$. It follows that the equation $f'(x)=0$, which is equivalent to $g(x)=p$,  has a unique root if and only if $p<1/2$.
Since $\lim_{x\to 0^+}f(x)=\infty$ and $\lim_{x\to\infty}f(x)=e$, the point $x$ for which $g(x)=p$ must be a global
minimum of $f(x)$ at which the value is striclty smaller than $e$. Conclusion: if $p<1/2$ there exists an $x>0$ such that $f(x)<e$. Q.E.D.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, uniquesolution. How did you find this solution?

Comment: @tchappyha  - I looked at the functions for $p<1/2$ and $p>1/2$ and noticed a clear difference, which prompted me to analyse the derivative.

Answer (score 3):

**Hint**: Solve the equation:

$$\left (1+\frac{1}{x}\right)^{x+p}=e$$

This will give you the point $x$ where the function crosses the horizontal $y=e$ (if and when it does). You'll get:

$$p(x)=-\frac{x\ln(1+\frac{1}{x})-1}{\ln(1+\frac{1}{x})}$$

You want to avoid crossing this line for all $x$, therefore the solution is:

$$\lim\limits_{x\to\infty}p(x)$$

That's a slightly tricky limit (I did it with Maple), but after some effort it evaluates to 1/2.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, Yiannis Galidakis.